# Minimize variation of an equation system

Tags: matrices, optimization, systems-of-equations, standard-deviation

We currently have a mathematical system of equations :

$ \hat{Y}_{N \times 1} = Y_{N \times 1} + a * T_{N \times 1} + b * K_{N \times K} \times M_{K \times 1} $

where

- $a$ and $b$ are constants
- $Y_{N \times 1}$ is a **fixed** vector of floats (distributed on $N(\mu, \sigma )$)
- $K_{N \times K}$ is a **fixed** matrix having only one "$1$" per row such as
  \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 \\ 
  0 & 1 \\ 
  0 & 1 
  \end{bmatrix}
- 24 <= $N$ <= 144
- 4 <= $K$ <= 24
- $T_{N \times 1}$ and $M_{K \times 1}$ are the 2 vectors of integers **to fit**  (let say between -20 and +20 for now)
- $\hat{Y}_{N \times 1}$ is a float vector of the result of the linear equation.

I would like to know if there is a way to find one solution to minimize the deviation over $\hat{Y}$ (Standard Deviation or Maximum deviation) ?

I know that with the current state of the problem, it doesn't exist one unique solution. There is missing constrains (N equations, N+K variables). The final optimal solution would be also to minimize the sum of $T_{N \times 1}$ and $M_{N \times 1}$ but it may make the problem even more complicated.

We could try to use Genetic Algorithms but maybe there is a more analytical approach, hence the question :)

Thanks in advance,

Nicolas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume T and M are the vectors to be optimally fitted, and they are constrained to be integers.

This can be formulated as an integer-constrained L2 (Euclidean) norm minimization problem (minimize least squares deviations) or as an integer-constrained infinity norm minimization problem (minimize the maximum absolute value of deviation)

I suggest using a package such as CVX (under MATLAN), CVXPY (under Python), or CVXR (under R) to formulate this and call the solver. You will need to have a mixed-integer capable solver installed (for CVX, that would be Gurobi or Mosek).

For the L2 norm formulation, it is more numerically robust and relaible when using one of the above packages to formulate the problem in terms of the norm, rather than the norm squared.

Here is roughly what it would look like for the L2 (Euclidean) norm in CVX:

```
% It is assumed that a, b, N, K, Yhat, Y are numerically populated as input data
cvx_begin
variable T(N) integer
variable M(N) integer
minimize(norm(Yhat - (Y + a*T + b*K*M),2))
-20 <= T <= 20
-20 <= M <= 20
cvx_end
```

For infinity norm minimization, just change the 2 to inf, i.e.,

```
minimize(norm(Yhat - (Y + a*T + b*K*M),inf))
```

At the conclusion of the program, CVX calls the solver. If CVX reports the problem has been solved, then `T` and `M` are available in your MATLAB session, and are populated with their optimal values.

Programs in the other packages are similar, mainly reflecting differences in the syntax of the language they are operating under.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! You are right, `T` and `M` are the 2 vectors to fit, I'll edit the question to clearly mention it.

I'll dig into this solver and mark it as solved as soon as I have tested it (using python, the rest of the code is already in this language) :) .

Comment: The CVXPY https://www.cvxpy.org/index.html should be similar. But I leave you to figure out the syntax.

Comment: The solution is very good, easy to code and fast to compute :). Unfortunately for now, I removed the "integer constrains" as it requires commercial solver (Gurobi or Mosek are not free for commercial use). Just for info in case people are looking for it, this is a solver table based on the problem (https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/advanced/index.html).

Comment: Yes. I did warn you about that ("You will need to have a mixed-integer capable solver installed (for CVX, that would be Gurobi or Mosek")). However, it appears there are "free" mixed-integer solvers available for CVXPY.  "CVXPY supports open source mixed-integer solvers GLPK_MI, CBC and SCIP". SCIP is the best of this bunch, but is not free for commercial. However, GLPK_MI (a.k.a. GPLK) and CBC are free. Both can handle mixed integer linear (MILP), but not quadratic or L2 norm. But I believe CVXPY ought to be able to call either GLPK_MI or CBC to solver the integer infinity norm problem (MILP)

Comment: If your problem has lower and upper bounds on all variables, then the free edition of CPLEX https://www.ibm.com/account/reg/us-en/signup?formid=urx-20028 which is limited to 1000 variables and 1000 constraints, will work if $N \le 250$ and can do both L2 and infinity norm minimization. If there are only bounds on one side, then CPLEX free edition could handle $N \le 500$. I might be off a little on the limits on $N$, due to extra variables or constraints added by CVXPY . CPLEX is superior to all the "free" solvers and is toe to toe with Gurobi as a MILP or MISOCP (used for L2 norm) solver.

Comment: Note: The solution of the integer-constrained problem could be multiple orders of magnitude slower than the continuous variable problem.

Comment: I've installed GLPK and it works (using infinite norm) :). Fortunately there is still free versions existing. Thanks for all your helpful support.

Comment: CPLEX might be orders of magnitude faster than GLPK on integer infinity norm minimization, unless the problem is easy for GLPK. Basically, CPLEX is in the top tier of MILP solvers (along with Gurobi). GLPK is in the bottom tier. The difference between top tier and bottom tier on integer-constrained problems can be huge.